# Same div class with different css styles

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I am using wordpress and I have div whose classname is "page" on three different pages. Three pages slugs are 1. home 2. aboutus and 3. contactus.

I want the width of page class div on aboutus page to be different but I don't want to access the page html directly I mean supposing I only have the option of jquery to be enqueued and add some new id or class on about us page with variable width. So how can it be done.
Below is the code for three pages

on home page

```
<div class="page">

</div>
```

on about us page

```
<div class="page">

</div>
```

on contactus page

```
<div class="page">

</div>
```

CSS

```
div.page {width:1000px; height:auto;}
```

I don't want to manually change the html but want to use jquery to append some new class and define different width for about us page.

Comment: should already have all the classes needed on body tag to do this using css alone. Use a stylesheet in child theme

Comment: Thanks charlietfl ... well we have already got our page template in our theme which is defined in such a way that all the newly created pages will have this page class so what if I want a different width for about us page so how can I modify the behavior of aboutus page can I change it's width only for about us page. May be I use some code in functions.php to define a different style whenever about us page is opened. I hope you can understand what i want ... because if this can be done it means we can modify behavior of wordpress pagewise

Comment: isn't page slug  or page-id already on body as a class?

Comment: Yes you could do this without adding more classes to body, but then you should write some JS. For example a function that looks at the URL and applies the style for that URL for your `div class="page"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add to your body tag this php code to append class:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/body_class

(or check if it is not already added).then your about us page will have  code like that:

```
<body class="about-us page-12...">
 <div class="page">
```

then you will be able to write special css for this case:

```
.about-us div.page {width:500px; height:auto;}
```

Comment: As per the link you have shared I should use something like this <body <?php body_class( 'class-name' ); ?>>

Comment: well as per the link using <<?php body_class() ?>> will insert all the pages slugs in the body tag and what you have shown is probably the effect or the result of using this php body class line. Kindly confirm and is there no solution with jquery ... come on guys

Comment: you missed the dot in `about-us div.page`, it should be `.about-us div.page`. @Zeeshan  `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>` is very standard and built-in in most of the themes.

Comment: @sdcr totally right. I updated my answer, for future googlers